# Why does this method not match the defined signature?

Tags: java, websocket

I get syntax error on a method call that I don't understand:

```
The method connectToServer(Endpoint, ClientEndpointConfig, URI) in the type WebSocketContainer is not applicable for the arguments (WebsocketClientEndpoint, ClientEndpointConfig, URI)
```

The class `WebsocketClientEndpoint` extends `Endpoint` and should match the signature `connectToServer(Class<? extends Endpoint> endpointClass, ClientEndpointConfig cec, URI path)`.  But it doesn't.  I get a syntax error in eclipse.

What Am I missing?

Here is the code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.websocket.ClientEndpoint;
import javax.websocket.ClientEndpointConfig;
import javax.websocket.CloseReason;
import javax.websocket.ContainerProvider;
import javax.websocket.OnClose;
import javax.websocket.OnMessage;
import javax.websocket.OnOpen;
import javax.websocket.Session;
import javax.websocket.WebSocketContainer;
import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;

import org.glassfish.tyrus.client.ClientProperties;
import org.glassfish.tyrus.client.auth.AuthConfig;
import org.glassfish.tyrus.client.auth.Credentials;
import org.glassfish.tyrus.core.wsadl.model.Endpoint;

/**
 */
@ClientEndpoint
public class WebsocketClientEndpoint extends Endpoint
{

Session userSession = null;

private MessageHandler messageHandler;

public WebsocketClientEndpoint(URI endpointURI)
{
    try
    {
        ClientEndpointConfig.Configurator configurator = new ClientEndpointConfig.Configurator()
        {
            public void beforeRequest(Map<String, List<String>> headers)
            {
                headers.put("Authorization",
                        Arrays.asList("Basic " + DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary("user:password".getBytes())));
            }
        };

        ClientEndpointConfig clientConfig = ClientEndpointConfig.Builder.create().configurator(configurator)
                .build();

        WebSocketContainer container = ContainerProvider.getWebSocketContainer();

        container.connectToServer(this, clientConfig, endpointURI);  //Signature mismatch here
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

... websocket callbacks 
}
```

Comment: `Class<? extends Endpoint>` and `Endpoint` are two very different things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `connectToServer` takes `javax.websocket.Endpoint` but you are passing object that extends `org.glassfish.tyrus.core.wsadl.model.Endpoint` which is totally incompatible class and does not extends `javax.websocket.Endpoint`.